# To set point on the map in Codename One

Tags: dictionary, codenameone

In my app user must set point on the map and send coordinates to UI. In MapComponent i didn't find any callback function for this. How can I implement this function?

If this is not provided, are there any callback functions of the parent classes for this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pointer events in the map or form to detect taps and add a layer to the map such as `PointsLayer` etc. to draw anything you want.

You might want to take a look at the native [map support though](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/mapping-natively), it does contain simplified coordinates like that.

Comment: I'm looking for callback functions or any events in this classes, but found only addActionListener in PointsLayer class. And trying to create ActionListener with test body ( Log.p(evt.getSource().toString()); ), but nothing happens

Comment: You will need to either derive the class to override pointer events or use the pointer events of the form. Why aren't you using the native map binding?

Comment: I didn't want to spend too much time for this task. But I made it through native maps and looks more fine and faster. And the necessary functions are already available. Once again thanks for the help.